# Derive a formula for calculation of new co-ordinates of a point when the c-ordinate axes $x$ and $y$ are rotated by an angle $\theta$.

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates, rotations

I was studying rotation of co-ordinate axes. There was an article given in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes about it. However, I don't get the *derivation* section, the picture of which is attached below:[image]

[image]

However, I do not get how they write that $x',y'$, system, $P$ will have coordinates $(r,\alpha-\theta)$? Wouldn't it be $(r,\alpha+\theta)$? I am not quite getting it...

Comment: This is, at first view, counter intuitive : but imagine that a same point  $M$ has certain coordinates with respect to the old axes ; rotating the old axes into new axes counterclockwise, keeping $M$ fixed, the new coordinates of $M$, i.e., the coordinates of $M$ wrt the new axes are "less than before", more exactly it looks like $M$ has gone in the other direction,  i.e.,clockwise.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks I do get it now...

Comment: Another simpler 1D explanation : I am on a train, looking at the landscape : I see a cow just in front of me on the border of the rails ; when the train has done +100 meters, I see now the cow 100 meters backwards i.e., at minus 100.

Comment: In rotations it is always important to distinguish whether you are rotating a point or trhe coordinate axes.  One is the inverse of the other.  A typical first treatment of rotations normally addresses the rotation of points in a fixed coordinate system.  This is a little easier to understand.  It is pretty easy to see that rotation of a point in one direction is the same as rotation of the coordinate system in the other.

Comment: @Tpofofn With keywords "active and passive transformations" or "alias/alibi" you find [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_and_passive_transformation)